# How to know what log levels used in production spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I am wondering if there is a way to know what are the logging levels set in spring boot application, which is running on production. I know I can check some logging level statements in application.yml. But I am not sure if it is edited after starting the application.
So, I want to confirm what logging levels are used in the application without stopping or restarting.
Can you provide inputs on this?

Answer (score 1):

If actuators are enabled on your project you can call the `/actuator/loggers` endpoint:
$`curl 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers' -i -X GET`

For more [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#loggers-all)